# Archive Parent / Child Table Hierarchy in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, archiving

If I have a Parent and Child table in MySQL related by a foreign key, is it possible using a SQL statement to move certain rows from Parent and the related rows from Child into archive tables (e.g. Parent_Archive and Child_Archive) in an atomic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transactions - their whole purpose is to make the series of SQL statements atomic.

For example (NOT very optimized - can be improved with temp table):

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT Child_Archive 
SELECT DISTINCT 
Child.* FROM Child, Parent
WHERE Child.FK = Parent.PK
  AND Parent.something=11; 

DELETE Child WHERE FK IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PK FROM Parent WHERE Parent.something=11); 

INSERT Parent_Archive
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Parent WHERE Parent.something=11;

DELETE Parent WHERE Parent.something=11;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Assuming Parent_Archive and Child_Archive have the same FK constraints as Parent and Child, won't the first insert fail because the parent isn't there yet?

Comment: @Eric J. - It will. I am unsure of why would an archive table have such a constraint at all, though (I would not put one in). If that's the design, the solution is the one I mentioned above as "better performing" - you go with creating a temp table of PKs/FKs to archive first, and then re-order queries above in the order you alluded to (insert into P_A, insert into C_A, delete C, delete P)